# Does downloading a Windows 10 preview update get an ISO or just delta updates, similar to Windows Update?

Tags: download, windows-update, iso-image, windows-10-preview, bandwidth

I'm not on a metered connection, so I want to know if Windows 10 TP is going to start downloading a 5gb ISO or just the updated files when I click the 'Download now' button on the Previews tab under Update & Recovery.

If getting an ISO is the only way, then I'd rather use a download manager, because there will be no way to throttle the speed or pause the download in the Windows Update method. If the download gets interrupted due to a connection drop (not uncommon), I'll just waste my quota.

Additionally, I'm running the preview on two other devices, so I don't want to download the new one three times.

Should I run the update or just grab a new ISO from the website?

Comment: If "I'm not on a metered connection", why am I worried about wasting my quota?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Update process downloads a large [electronic software distribution (ESD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_distribution) file, which is only a bit smaller compared to the ISO which contains a required setup.exe. It doesn't work like normal Windows Updates.

If you want to update several machines, download the ISO, mount the ISO, run `setup.exe` and select "Upgrade".

Comment: I was afraid this would be the case.

Answer (score -1):

Following feedback from the Windows Insider program, Build 9879 has been made available as an ISO. See [New build available to the Windows Insider Program](http://blogs.windows.com/bloggingwindows/2014/11/12/new-build-available-to-the-windows-insider-program/) on Blogging Windows. As magicandre1981 stated, the new build is installed as an operating system upgrade rather than an update.